# Tag a person when a property value change on a table

Tags: notion-api, notion

I would like to know if there is any way to @ someone on a Notion table only when the tag on a Select Property change (for example tag someone when the tag move from "Currently writing" to "Writing Done").

Hope you guys understand what I'm asking for!

Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

A bit hackish, but there is a solution:

You can use automations (paid) on the db for this:

- Make another db with at least two additional columns (always needs a title).
- Add one way `relation` column/property (to the original db).
- Add `person` column/property.

Create automation:

- Use "tag" (property edited) as the trigger.
- Use `Add page to (db)` as the action.
- Set the properties to relation: `@this page`.
- Set the person to whomever you wish to notify. They will receive a notification about the mention in the second db, and the relation will send them to the modified page upon clicking